# Can Safari 5.1 for Mac OS display favicons for bookmarks in the Bookmarks Bar?

Tags: macos, osx-lion, safari, bookmarks, favicon

When bookmarking a web site, most contemporary browser will display the site's favicon next to the bookmark, both in the bookmark view and the bookmark toolbar.

This is a useful feature. In the bookmark toolbar you can edit the name of the bookmark to be blank, effectively leaving the favicon there as an easily identifiable "button" from which to launch the bookmark. This allows you to make more effective user of the space in the bookmark toolbar. I use this approach effectively in Firefox, Chrome, and IE. For example, here is a portion of my Bookmarks Toolbar from Firefox:

[image]

However, in Safari, no favicon is ever displayed for bookmarks. In the full bookmark view only a generic globe icon is displayed. In the Bookmark Bar in Safari, no icon at all is displayed. This means the habit of removing the bookmark name and leaving the favicon is useless. Here's what the same configuration (synced between browsers via Xmarks) looks like in Safari:

[image]

That blank space is where the favicons *should* be. The bookmark is there -- if you hover over it, the blank space changes color to indicate the presence of a bookmark and a tooltip with the URL will pop up after about two seconds. However, it's quite unusable.

Is there an extension, plugin, or modification of some sort that will enable the display of favicons for bookmarks in Safari (OS X Lion 10.7.3, Safari version 5.1.3)?

Comment: I'm running Safari 5.1.7 in OSX 10.7.4, and I do get favicons in the standard bookmark menu and for bookmarks that are in a folder on the bookmark bar.  No icons for bookmarks directly in the bar, though.

Comment: @ChrisHerbert You are correct. I, too, do get favicons in the standard bookmark menu and for bookmarks in a folder on the bookmark bar *if* I have clicked on those bookmarks (which is reasonable). I can confirm that after upgrading to OS X Mountain Lion 10.8 and Safari 6.0, I still do not get any favicon at all for bookmarks in the bookmarks bar, even after clicking on the bookmark.

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that for whatever reason, there is no solution for this.  I've been looking for a work around every now and then for the past two years, and I've emailed Apple to petition them to fix this, as this is the *one* thing that forces me to use Firefox rather than Safari.

Comment: This is not answering the question. We're not a forum, so we'd like answers to actually contain solutions to the problem stated.

Comment: @slhck: "No" seems like a perfectly valid answer to me. Not every question can be answered in the affirmative.

Comment: @bahamat This answer was rambling all over the place about Apple not including some features. Please check the edit history. After Sathya's edit, not much is left of that. Also, there's a logical fallacy here: "No" can not always be a valid answer to a question — there might be an answer out there unless you can *definitely* prove that there will never be one, for whatever reason.

Comment: Non-answer. @bahamat In the context of StackExchange a non-answer provides no more value than staying silent, particularly because any one user's lack of a known answer may be due to ignorance of the solution rather than from no actual solution existing. In fact, a non-answer is counter-productive. If everyone posted "I don't know either" when posed with a question, the site would actually be *less* useful.